# Apple TV not detected by Xcode or iTunes

Tags: macos, xcode7, apple-tv

I am developing an Apple TV app using OSX 10.11.1, Xcode 7.1.1, and iTunes 12.2.2.25. My Apple TV is a 3rd generation model.

My Apple TV is not detected by my iMac. It's also not detected by iTunes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need an Apple TV 4th generation to develop apps. The 3rd generation Apple TV is not supported by the new tvOS platform.

Comment: Hi @stefan , Now I am using appleTV 4th Generation, Still its not detecting , What I need to do to detect my apple Tv in my MAC?

Comment: Have you registered your AppleTV at the AppleDeveloper Portal?

Comment: Yes,Just now Its detected in my Xcode, but not in iTunes.

Answer (score 0):

The truth is, XCode 7+ will actually show the Apple TV as unsupported, but listed in the device list. Also it will show up in the iTunes as Apple TV 3rd gen. You just cannot use the 3rd gen as development device.